# Scheme syntax-rules - Difference in variable bindings between (let) and (define)

Tags: macros, scheme, hygiene

The R<sup>5</sup>RS spec states that as part of the requirements for a macro defined using `syntax-rules`:

> If a macro transformer inserts a free reference to an identifier, the reference refers to the binding that was visible where the transformer was specified, regardless of any local bindings that may surround the use of the macro.

I am trying to understand how this works in practice. So for example, if I have the following code:

```
(define var 'original)

(define-syntax test-var
 (syntax-rules (var)
   ((_ var)
    var)
   ((_ pattern-var)
    'no-match)))
```

I would expect the following, if executed immediately after, to evaluate to `original`, which it does:

```
(test-var var)
```

And I would expect this one to be `no-match` since the `var` introduced into scope prior to `test-var` does not match the binding of `var` at macro definition:

```
(let ((var 1)) (test-var var))
```

However the following example has me puzzled:

```
(define var 'new-var)
(test-var var)
```

In Chicken Scheme, this evaluates to `new-var`. I would have expected it to be `no-match` for the same reasons as the previous `(let)` example. I thought that perhaps this was an issue with using `define` twice, but the result is still `new-var` even if I use `(set! var 'new-var)`

Does anyone have any insight as to what is going on here? What should happen per R<sup>5</sup>RS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the usual trick that Schemes have when dealing with redefinitions on the REPL -- treating them as a mutation for the existing binding.  So the second `define` is not really creating a new binding, and instead it just `set!`s the existing one.

Comment: Interesting... although this behavior occurs not just on the REPL but also when running via the interpreter or even a compiled version of the code.

Comment: So is it correct to say that this is not specified behavior, but most schemers would expect it to work this way?

Comment: Well, by "REPL" I mean any use of "the implicit global namespace", in contrast to using a module system where such redefinitions are usually forbidden.

Comment: If you want to be picky, then R⁵RS says: “At the top level of a program, a definition `(define <variable> <expression>)` has essentially the same effect as the assignment expression `(set! <variable> <expression>)` if `<variable>` is bound.”.  So I'd guess that schemers would expect this.  But working without a module system is fairly outdated, and code that depends on the toplevel should be restricted to quick games and debugging...  At least IMO.